# How can I access files from Linux LVM?

Tags: partitioning, windows, filesystem, files, lvm

I just migrated from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 16. While installing Ubuntu I checked for having Linux LVM and since then I'm facing a big problem of accessing the data from the drives I had in Windows.

Here is the result of `sudo fdisk -l` command :

[image: sudo fdisk]

Here is the result of `lsblk` command :

[image: lsblk]

Please help!

Comment: It looks like there are only linux related partitions i.e. windows drives have been wiped out.

Comment: Instead of posting images, please add any Terminal output directly in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @J.J.Hakala So that means all my data is lost?

Comment: @SunilNeurgaonkar It does look like that. It could require an experienced user to recover some data. If you had multiple windows drives and your ubuntu installation does not take much space yet then at least some of the data might be still there.

Comment: You could create a Windows live USB stick (with third party software) and look, if you can see your data there

Comment: Gparted has some simple data recovery (when gpart is installed). Try it from a Ubuntu live disk

Comment: @Motte001 Yes. I have installed Gparted. I will look from the try and access it with Windows. Thanks.